# Issue in crontab job

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, cron

I have to write a cron job to execute a java class every after 8 hours. To test, I wrote a simple cron using :

```
crontab -e 
*/1 * * * * echo $PATH
```

When I do, `crontab -u <user> -l`, it prints the entire cron file with above job listed. But I want to ascertain that my job is getting executed as intended. I don't see output of `"echo $PATH"` every minute. How can I see this output...?

Comment: You don't see it because it does not run in your session. Do redirect it to a file and track if it gets appended: `*/1 * * * * echo $PATH >> /tmp/dummy_file`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it says that output of the crontab will sent to the user via email (unless redirected). I was hoping to use that option since in Production, I will not have access to see the redirected output in the file.

Comment: You wont see the output of echo but if you would like to see if cron ran the you could check your logs 

by default on some linux distributions it goes to `/var/log/syslog` and then just use grep on that file  `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: It should mail the output to you in every minute.

Comment: Which email is it sending..? Where to specify this..?

Comment: The system will email your system account, if you don't have a forward or don't use that local mailbox you can tell cron to email you by adding `MAILTO=user@example.com` to the top of your cron file.